# LDAP web page authorization

Tags: authentication, ldap, html

I want to provide authentication for my webpage using an LDAP server, that I set up. I`ve set up the server using this tutorial: http://www.krugerville.com/centos6/configuring-openldap-server-on-centos-6.html.

Then I created a group 'users' using the ldif file I found here (under group authentication): 
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html#LDAP

My domain is: bimi-test.fm.abc-dc.it.

Is it ok, if I replace the "o=stooges" with "dc=bimi-test,dc=fm,dc=abc-dc,dc=it", so that the entry would look like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from All
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Stooges Web Site: Login with user id"
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://bimi-test.fm.abc-dc.it:389/dc=bimi-test,dc=fm,dc=abc-dc,dc=it?uid?sub
   AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=Manager,dc=bimi-test,dc=fm,dc=abc-dc,dc=it"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword pepi
   AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
   AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
   Require ldap-group cn=users,ou=group,dc=bimi-test,dc=fm,dc=abc-dc,dc=it
   Require ldap-attribute gidNumber=100
   Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

I there anything else besides editing the httpd.conf that I should edit to get the login window? Nothing is happening here...I can access my site without any authorization. :(

**UPDATE: Ok, so a friend gave me his httpd.conf, which I edited. This worked for me:**

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Deny from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://bimi-test.fm.abc-dc.it/ou=people,dc=bimi-test,dc=fm,dc=abc-dc,dc=it?uid?sub
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthName "Ldap admin"
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

We had a lot of people who had issue with this and put up some notes on the configuration here:
http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/TomcatAndLDAP